# GPS location is on/off in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to do like, when the app start, app check for iPhone GPS ON or OFF? if GPS off then app quite.

Comment: iPhone apps should never be quit programmatically. If you want your app to be on the app store, you cannot at at any time, exit the app programmatically - because it looks like a crash, and Apple will reject it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you want exactly to know, location service or does user granted access to the location service? 
If first, than depending on iOS version you can use:

on iOS pre 4.x:

```
CLLocationManager *testLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
BOOL servicesEnabled = [testLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];
[testLocationManager release];
```

on iOS 4.x+:

`BOOL servicesEnabled = [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];`

If second, than:

on iOS pre 4.x: there is no quick snippet, you have to wait if *didFailWithError* or *didUpdateToLocation* will be called and if second, than user granted access

on iOS 4.x+:

`BOOL accessGranted = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized;`

And than easily use *exit(0)* if you option not reached. And yes, try notify user about what you is about to quit the app.

Comment: Exiting programmatically would result in your app being rejected.

Comment: No, it won't, it just unpleasant and Apple in HIG asks somehow notify user about that and than if this is really necessary you may exit.

Comment: there is a 95% chance that Apple will reject your app for exiting programmatically. They strongly discourage it, and I wouldn't recommend tempting them.

Comment: You might want to watch this years WWDC video covering location services then. They make it quite clear that they expect a location based application to offer some sort of functionality, even if location based services are turned off. Exiting is meant for critical situations which you cannot recover from - it is not necessary to exit only because you can't get a location right away.

Comment: [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] always returns "YES"

Comment: @virata even if you will turn off location service in Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services -> Location Services switch to "Off"?

Comment: @moonlight,No.when location services are off then result is "FALSE". Actually what I need is to detect whenever actually GPS is being used (observe that gps arrow on top right of status bar.Its not always shown.It appears only when any navigation app is launched.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) and ask it for `locationServicesEnabled`. This will tell you if location services are available.

Note however that Apple does not allow apps to quit on their own, the user needs to press the home button instead. If you discover location services are unavailable, you need to tell the user that your app needs them and they should be activated for your app to work properly.